# A Bernoulli differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is
$$y'(x)=\alpha \, y(x)-\beta \, y^2(x)$$

If I understand this correctly, the condition is $y \ne 0$ means $y$ might be the parameter of another function like $\alpha$ here could be a $\sin$ function. Is my understanding correct?

This looks like it can be solved using Bernoulli's method. But I'm just quite unsure. Someone gives me a hint?

Comment: Homogeneous/non-homogeneous means nothing for a non-linear ODE. There is no condition $y\ne0,$ and non-linear means $\beta\ne0.$ You can convert your ODE to a linear one by [Bernoulli's general method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation). I think you should replace you title by: A Bernoulli ODE $y'(x)=\alpha y(x)-\beta y^2(x).$ And replace this (in the title and in the text) by $y'=\alpha y-\beta y^2$ if your $\alpha,\beta$ are supposed to be non-constant functions of $x.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Do separation of variables
$$\int \frac{dy}{ay-by^2}=\int dx$$

Comment: can you do that if its non linear?

Comment: Yes, separability is most basic.and it is allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider letting $y = \frac{1}{f}$ in the differential equation
$$ y^{'} = \alpha \, y - \beta \, y^2 $$
to obtain the differential equation
$$ f^{'} + \alpha \, f = \beta. $$
This equation can then be seen to admit the following solution:
\begin{align}
f' + \alpha \, f &= \beta \\
e^{- \alpha \, x} \, \frac{d}{dx} \left( e^{\alpha x} \, f\right) &= \beta \\
e^{\alpha \, x} \, f &= \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \, e^{\alpha x} + c_{0} \\
f(x) &= \frac{\beta}{\alpha} + c_{0} \, e^{- \alpha \, x}.
\end{align}
This yields
$$ y(x) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta + c_{0} \, \alpha \, e^{- \alpha \, x}}. $$